# How to check if Current Hour falls between certain range

Tags: java

I am trying to check if Current Hour  falls in between `7AM` and `10AM`

I am doing it this way

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTime(new Date());               
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); 
if(hour >= 7 && hour <= 10)              
{

}
```

Please tell me if this is a valid approach to follow

Comment: Yes, it is a valid approach.

Comment: Did you test it ? if it doesn't work what is the problem ?

Comment: yes, it's valid, also `cal.setTime(new Date()); ` is not needed

Comment: If its between 7AM and 10AM then it should be `hour >= 7 && hour < 10`

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is a valid approach. You could also use the new Time API (needs Java 8)

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
...
int hour = LocalTime.now().getHour();
```

It's a bit shorter to get the hour. There is also an overloaded `now(ZoneId zoneId)` method.

Or make it a one liner with a temporal query (also needs Java 8):

```
Boolean isBetween7and10AM = LocalTime.now().query(date -> date.get(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY) >=7 &&
            date.get(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY) < 10);
```

Comment: Just remember that this approach requires the (new) Java 8 runtime in your runtime environment.

Comment: That's true. Just added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. This looks fine. Remember that this `Calendar` field is dependent on the timezone.

BTW: Put the starting curly brace at the end of the previous line, since this is the common code formatting style.

:-)